# What's the trick for running Jade template in C9 Cloud IDE?

Tags: node.js, express, pug, cloud9-ide

I am trying to run a simple web app with Express (nodejs) in [C9 Cloud IDE](https://c9.io/) but happen that when I start the app the IDE treats `.jade` file as JavaScript, and try to interpret it, giving lots of errors.

For example, Jade file:

```
h1 Sign Up
form(action="/user", method="POST")
    input(type="text", name="user[name]", placeholder="Type your desired user name")
    input(type="password", name="user[password]", placeholder="Type your password")
    input(type="password", name="user[passwordCheck]", placeholder="Type your password again")

    button(value="SIGN UP!")
```

Error I get:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { h1 Sign Up
                                                              ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Is there any configuration for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

[Cloud 9](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9) IDE uses ACE text editor with bundled syntax highlighting support for JS, HTML, CSS and mixed modes. From [ACE](http://ace.ajax.org/#nav=howto) guide:

> By default, the editor supports plain text mode. All other language
>   modes are available as separate modules, loaded on demand like this:

```
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
```

So try setting it for `ace/mode/jade`

Comment: Hummm... So where should I call `editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/jade");`?

Comment: If you are embedding ace into your site, include it in your code. How are you calling jade file.

Comment: No, I am using the Cloud9 IDE to code a small project and I am making use of JADE templates. I get this error when I start my app at c9.